# Most efficient way to select ending item of an array?

Tags: r

I'm looking for the most efficent way (i.e. the lesser keys pressed) to indexing the last element of an array.

Then something like

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
n <- length(a)
b <- a[n]
```

should not be used, I would like to use just a single command.

In the example above I could use

```
b <- a[length(a)]
```

but I wonder if something shorter does exist.

Let I want to select a part of an array, like

```
a <- seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1)
b <- a[3:length(a)]
```

Is there a shorter way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the first case, you can use:

```
> tail(a, 1)
[1] 3
```

Not that that really qualifies as shorter.

For the second example

```
> tail(a, -2)
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

but in general; no there is nothing shorter. R doesn't have an inplace operator or syntactic sugar for the end of a vector or array, in the sense of something that evaluates to the end of the array. That is what `length()` can be used for.

Answer (score 6):

Use `tail()` to get the tail end of an object:

```
x <- 1:100
```

By default, `tail()` returns 6 elements...

```
tail(x)
[1]  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

... but you can change that:

```
tail(x, 10)
 [1]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

---

Similarly, there is `head()` to get the first elements:

```
head(x, 7)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Is there a nice way to make this work on columns? `?tail` says it grabs rows in the 2D case.